# xamarin android "Preserve data/cache" doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile

Every time I deploy my android project, the app data has been wiped. This applies both for Visual studio for mac and windows. I have previously been work with Xamarin and android development on a samsung s7 which also had the issue, but I some how fixed that, I just can't remember how. Now my new S9 has the same issue where "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" is not respected.

I have tried toggle the check mark for "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" several times, restarting the phone, updating OS visual studio and android sdks, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Then probably the issue is in your code, either state is not preserved properly or you wipe it after app restart or at some point. Just debug your app.

Comment: Pretty sure it has nothing to do with the code, but with the s9. Tried with huawei p10 and google pixel without any issues.

Comment: I have the same problem. And I also use S9, but it worked in the past. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: It actually just started working as expected today and it is really frustrating because I'm not sure what fixed the issue. I have updated VS for mac and xamarin except xamarin android because this have previuosly caused a lot of issues.